# The violet, purple and scarlet material, what are they?

Tags: exodus, priestly, garment

Exodus 28:5-6, 8 & 15 NASB

> 5 They shall take the gold, **the violet, the purple, the scarlet
> material**, and the fine linen. 6 “They shall also make the ephod of gold, **of violet, purple, and
> scarlet material**, and fine twisted linen, the work of the skilled
> embroiderer.

> 8 The skillfully woven band of its
> overlay, which is on it, shall be like its workmanship, of the same
> material: of gold, **of violet and purple and scarlet material** and
> fine twisted linen.

> 15 “You shall make a breastpiece of judgment, the work of a skilled
> embroiderer; like the work of the ephod you shall make it: of gold,
> **of violet, purple, and scarlet material**, and fine twisted linen you shall make it.

What fabric is the violet, purple and scarlet material on the priestly garment made of? Are they linen yarn to not break Deu 22:11 Do not wear clothes of wool and linen woven together.

Answer (score 3):

I consulted with a historical costumer (my wife) and received the following insights:

**Fine colors**

The colors selected were rare, difficult to produce, and carried symbolic meaning:

- Blue/Violet - heaven, sky, abode of God (note that Tyrian purple could produce a range of blue-purple shades)
- Purple - royalty
- Scarlet - can refer to a type of weave or color (see Appendix)

Most people did not wear these colors; the attire of the priests set them apart, reflecting the sanctity of the temple.

--

**Linen vs. Wool**

Linen fiber is cellulose, long & skinny (from bottom to top of the flax plant), wool is a protein fiber twisted upon itself, creating lots of spaces for dye to reside, making wool much easier to dye.

Dyeing linen to great visual effect would (unlike wool) require using a mordant, which weakens the integrity of the textile. This was not desirable for a garment intended to last for generations (see below)

--

**Spun or embroidered**

Deut. 22:11 & Lev. 19:19 indicate that the Israelites were not to spin linen & wool fibers together.

Embroidering wool on linen is therefore much more likely. Much better colors are obtained by dying wool (vs linen); linen creates a smooth, easy-to-stitch base surface.

The garment probably consisted of undyed white linen worn against the skin (easy to wash) with expensive wool embroidery over it. If the gold were woven into the linen it would be (nearly) impossible to wash/clean the garment. The more expensive attire was designed to be long-lasting, passed from father to son (see Exodus 29:29) and therefore had to be something that could be cleaned.

--

**Conclusion**

Gold metal thread & brightly colored woolen thread were embroidered onto a fine linen surface.

---

**Appendix-Scarlet**

The meaning of the word “scarlet” has changed since the time of the King James translators, and with it, the interpretation we read back onto Hebrew, Greek, and English texts.

In the English of Tudor fashion (just drawing to a close when KJV was written), “scarlet” was a reference to a specific type of high-quality woven wool. Because it was a luxury item, it was often dyed in expensive colors, such as the eye-catching red we now associate with the word “scarlet”.

Definitions in Tudor English:

- Scarlet: “Broadcloth of the highest quality; dyed in kermes, usually
  red. Used for petticoats, waistcoats, hose, gowns, cloaks, linings.”
- Broadcloth: “Finest woollen cloth, 54 to 63 inches wide (hence the
  name), of plain weave, with a weft of good-quality carded
  short-staple wool, well-fulled, a nap raised on it and then sheared;
  for gowns, coats, cassocks”

(definitions are taken from “The Tudor Tailor – Reconstructing sixteenth-century dress” p. 36)

The Tudor Tailor definitions for these words cite sources from 1546, 1573, and 1592, the later of which would be well within the lifetimes of the future King James translators.

Comment: Your diversity astounds me. upvoted +1.

Comment: @HoldToTheRoad Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 2):

The NASB in, in this verse (Ex 28:5, 6, 8, 15) unhelpful.  Let me quote some other equally correct versions of Ex 28:5 -

- NIV: Have them use gold, and blue, purple and scarlet **yarn**, and fine linen.
- NLT: So give them fine linen cloth, gold thread, and blue, purple, and scarlet **thread**.
- ESV: They shall receive gold, blue and purple and scarlet **yarns**, and fine twined linen.
- BSB: They shall use gold, along with blue, purple, and scarlet **yarn**, and fine linen.
- NKJV: “They shall take the gold, blue, purple, and scarlet **thread**, and the fine linen

Thus, the High Priest's cloths were made of fine twisted linen in the most expensive and exquisite designs.  [Wool is not mentioned here at all in the book of Exodus.] The dyes used for such colors were expensive and rare and result was very expensive clothing for the high priest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dottard